# Extract Zip or Rar files using the terminal on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, zip, rar

I have just started to work on a Mac terminal for a school work.

My question is: which command do I have to write to extract files of a .zip or .rar file by using the terminal only? Is it the same command to open all types of compressed files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what's available on a stock OS X installation, which is why I'm not making this an answer, but for zip files, have you tried `unzip`?

Comment: I have just tried to use this command and it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually use `tar` or `zip` for file compression. Something like

```
tar -x ~/somefile.zip
```

will extract the `somefile.zip` in your home folder to sub-folders defined in the zip.

```
tar -czf ~/mynewzip.zip ~/datafolder
```

will compress `~/datafolder` to newzip.zip in your home folder.  Make sure to read the man page for tar or zip for more details.

Comment: This answer doesn't mention the RAR.

Answer (score 3):

#### For `zip` files

In the terminal (at `.zip` location):

```
unzip <filename>
```

---

#### For `rar` files

Try using Homebrew...

In a terminal type:

```
brew install rar
```

Now to use it just navigate to your file directory and type:

- To view the `rar` file:

```
unrar l <filename>
```

- To extract the `rar` file in the same location:

```
unrar x <filename>
```

- To extract the `rar` file in the desired location:

```
unrar x <filename>
```

In case you face any permission issue: **Developer cannot be verified**.
`'rar'` cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
**Follow this process:**
Open System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> General -> Click the lock to make changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of 2023, the `unrar` installed via `brew` does not work on newest versions of MacOS. You'll get the error: '“unrar” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information. Homebrew Cask downloaded this file...'

Comment: I just checked it on my latest version of macOS, It's working fine (able to download with the above command). If you are getting permission issues, I mentioned a solution for this at the end of the post.

Comment: I think my issue is not MacOS version. My mistake. My laptop is M1 processor. Maybe that's why it doesn't work for me. However, I answered my solution below. It's universal and works on all machines. See **The Unarchiver** answer.

Answer (score 3):

`brew install unar`

It's the CLI version of https://theunarchiver.com/command-line

EDIT:

to use, simply

`unar my_archive.rar`

Comment: Hello, the question is how to extract the files, not how to install software to extract them.

Comment: Here is how to extract files using the above mentioned software: `unar my_file.rar`

Answer (score 0):

I guess following command will do the purpose:

`unrar x <file_name>.rar`

If unrar is not installed, you can use:

`brew install unrar`

Comment: Doesn't work in latest MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is the very popular, free, stable, maintained software to extract any compressed files out there. TAR, ZIP, RAR, TGZ, GZ, Z, 7ZIP, you name it. **The Unarchiver**.

The software has the CLI version too - https://theunarchiver.com/command-line

Can be installed as a regular GUI app via the AppStore if you wish - https://apps.apple.com/au/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12

To unpack any file archive via CLI you'd need to install the software via [brew](https://brew.sh) and simply run it like this:

```sh
brew install unar
unar your_archive.any
```